# Best way to build a custom Django CMS

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-cms

I am new to Django, but heard it was promising when attempting to create a a custom CMS.

I am looking to get started, but their seems to be a lack of documentation, tutorials, etc on how to actually get something like this going.

I am curious if their are any books/tutorials/guides that can help me get started with CMS django building.

PS- I have heard of django-cms, but am unsure what exactly it is and how it is different from django.

Comment: It is an application built using django framework

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of tutorials that has been put together by authors of Two Scoops of Django. http://twoscoopspress.com/pages/django-tutorials

Answer (score 0):

django CMS is a CMS on top of django. It supports multiple languages really well and plays nice together with your own django apps. The basic idea is that you define `placeholders` in your template and then are able to fill those placeholders with content plugins. A content plugin can be a anything from text, picture, twitter stream, multi column layout etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this, it's about creating placeholder that can be replaced later, which is what CMS is, technically
https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/02-templates_placeholders.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32168734)